# Counting multiples in a range

Tags: java, math, division

So, using Java I am trying to figure out the number of integers that are divisable by 2, 3, and 5 in a certain range [a,b]. As I wanted it to work for large numbers, I coded it using the inclusion exclusion principle. However, I still have no idea how to complete my code, i.e. write code that would calculate multiples of x (2, 3, 5, 10, 15 and 30).

Here's my incomplete code:

```
class Multiples {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long m = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        long a = sc.nextLong();
        long b = sc.nextLong();

        ??????????

        m = multiplesOf2 + multiplesOf3 + multiplesOf5 - multiplesOf6 - multiplesOf10 - multiplesOf15 + multiplesOf30; 

        System.out.println(m);
        }
    }
```

So, obviously I'm missing the '????' part. I tried calculating the multiples (in this case of 2) with the expression:

```
multiplesOf2c = Math.ceil(a/2)*2;
multiplesOf2f = Math.floor(a/2)*2;
multiplesOf2 = ((multiplesOf2d - multiplesOf2f)/2 + 1);
```

However, this doesn't seem to do the trick. The result is sometimes correct, but in most cases it's off by 1 or 2. Any ideas, please?

Comment: If you want to see how many numbers are divisible by X in the range [0,N] its Math.floor(N/X).

Comment: Multiples of 6 includes all multiples of 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

Simple but not much good when considering performance!

```
int counterX=0; int x=// your desired number
for (long i=a; i<=b; i++) {
    if(i%x==0){
        counterX++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach, maybe this could help you:

```
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        long a = sc.nextLong();
        long b = sc.nextLong();
        int flag;
        int m=0;
        String _mul235="";
        String _mulOf2="Multiples 2: ";
        String _mulOf3="Multiples 3: ";
        String _mulOf5="Multiples 5: ";
        for (long i=a;i<b;i++){
            flag=0;
            if(i%2==0) {
                flag+=1;
                _mulOf2 += i + " ";
            }                
            if(i%3==0) {
                flag+=1;;
                _mulOf3 += i + " ";
            }                
            if(i%5==0) {
                flag+=1;;
                _mulOf5 += i + " ";
            }                

            if (flag==3){
                m+=1;
                _mul235+= i + " ";
            }                    
        }
        System.out.println("Range: From " + a + " to "+b);            
        System.out.println("Integer multiples of (2, 3 y 5): "+ m + "\n[ "+_mul235+"]");
        System.out.println("Checking:");
        System.out.println(_mulOf2);
        System.out.println(_mulOf3);
        System.out.println(_mulOf5);
```